# issue in hiding navigation bar

Tags: ios, navigationbar

i add navigation bar in rootController like below in appdelegate

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
@synthesize navController;


birthDateTableViewController =[[BirthDateTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BirthDateTableViewController" bundle:nil];



navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:birthDateTableViewController]autorelease];


[window addSubview:navController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
```

now as i want to hide it in other view because they have their own navigation bars 
     so i use following code for hiding rootViewControllers navigation bar but its not     hiding please tell me what i am doing wrong  i do this for hiding in viewDidLoad

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];
```

application get crash when it reach above line 
         i have tried this which is not working 
         [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];

Comment: HY.. your problem is still ....

Comment: What your crash log says ?

Comment: it says nothing just stuck and Boom over  if i use this then nothing happen its not getting hided [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];

Comment: [window setRootViewController:navController];

Comment: What is the version of your ios sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS < 6.0 use

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

For iOS >= 6.0 use

```
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: Bhargavi problem bijo kaikj hato ae to solve thai gau. pan thank you so much answer aapva mate :) Jay Jay Garavi Gujarat ha ha this is second time that u have answered my question :)

Comment: me allready app delegate ma navigation bar banavelu hatuj je mare badhej use karvu joiye pan hu darek view nu navigation bar banavto hato aa bathu delete kari ne app delegate nu navigation vapariu aetle hide ke appear karvani magaj marij nai :) Te MCA kariu chhe?

Answer (score 2):

Your appDelegate doesn't have a link to the navController but your viewController has one! So change your code for:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: i did this its not working thats why i made object of app delegate and that all its not working

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine..

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view controller's -(void)viewWillAppear method in which you don't want to show navigation bar.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather using...

```
  [window addSubview:navController.view];
```

Use this...

```
  [window addSubview:self.navController];
```

And in your viewControllers, use this...

```
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```